# namenode/datanode not starting. Log file contains no text

Tags: hadoop

I have read almost all the threads in stackoverflow before posting this question.

I have installed hadoop 0.22 on Ubuntu 12.04. ((I am new to Ubuntu and Hadoop)). I installed hadoop by following the instructions given at http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-single-node-cluster/. The only issue now I have is getting the namenode and datanode start up. When I execute the start-dfs.sh command I get the following message in the terminal and the two nodes do not start. If I check the logs *.out, I see nothing in these files. The file is empty. The common solution suggested by many threads and website is to reformat the namenode, which I have done several times without any failure, but I still cannot get the namenode started. I am really stuck. Please help

I executed the following command

> starting namenode, logging to
>   /usr/local/hadoop/bin/../logs/hadoop-hduser-namenode-pradeepUbuntu.out
>
> localhost: starting datanode, logging to
>   /usr/local/hadoop/bin/../logs/hadoop-hduser-datanode-pradeepUbuntu.out
>
> localhost: starting secondarynamenode, logging to
>   /usr/local/hadoop/bin/../logs/hadoop-hduser-secondarynamenode-pradeepUbuntu.out

following is the output after executing jps command followed by start-dfs.sh command to get the above output.

> 9041 Jps
>
> 8982 SecondaryNameNode

Comment: Logs are written in **.log** files and not .out files. Please share NN and DN log with us. Also, your config files.

Comment: As per the terminal output it is .out to which logs are written, so what is .out then? Under which directory can I find the log files. What are NN And DN logs? Which config files you want to see. I can post their contents. Thanks for looking into this.

Comment: .log and .out files actually do the same thing, but with a slight difference. .out files are only written to when the process is starting. After process has started successfully, the .out files are truncated. By contrasts, all log messages can be found in the .log files, including the process start-up messages that are sent to the .out files.

Comment: You can find log files under your HADOOP_HOME/logs directory. I want to see core-site.xml, hdfs-site.xml and mapred-site.xml files as none of your processes are running except SNN.

Comment: Okay. I got every fixed now. This is what I did. 1) I took the backup of all files in the conf folder. 2) Removed the hadoop folder and re-created the hadoop folder 3) Copied  all the backed up copy  of configuration files into conf folder 4) removed the /app/hadoop/tmp folder 4) re-created tmp folder 5) formated namenode by executing /usr/local/hadoop/bin/hadoop namenode -format. After this I executed start-dfs.sh and start-mapred.sh and voila!!! I saw all servers running fine.